# android: retrofit2 post giving error but successful?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I am attempting to send an item from my app to my database using post.
post does not return anything, its a void in the web service.

my service interface function

```
@POST("SaveDailyScan")
suspend fun save(@Body itemModel: ItemModel) : Call<ResponseBody>
```

I have tried it with just Call void but it wasn't actually making it to the database so I switched to ResponseBody.

code that calls it.

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        val call = service.saveDailyScan(itemModel)
    }
```

the error which I receive is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Process: com.r.test, PID: 7307
java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1401)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

not really sure what is wrong with it. It does insert it into my database right before it crashes.

Comment: this is a parsing error of `ItemModel`. what does that class look like, and how are you creating it?

Comment: What's wrong with just,
`@POST("SaveDailyScan")
suspend fun save(@Body itemModel: ItemModel): ResponseBody`

Comment: @DominicFischer apparently nothing, I am new to retrofit2 so everything I have been finding seemed to want call<something>

Comment: Was that the answer then? Should I make a proper answer for you to accept?

Comment: @DominicFischer you can as that did solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For suspend functions, you don't (need to) use the `Call<...>` type.
So just `ResponseBody` will suffice, like so.

```
@POST("SaveDailyScan")
suspend fun save(@Body itemModel: ItemModel): ResponseBody
```